# What is the proper way to use memset on a struct element?

Tags: c, struct, memset

I'm trying to use memset on a struct element like so:

```
memset( &targs[i]->cs, 0, sizeof( xcpu ) );
```

However, doing so gives me a segmentation fault. I neither understand why this is failing, nor how I can make it work. **What is the proper way to use memset on an element of a struct, and why does my method not work?**

Line which allocates memory for targs:

```
eargs **targs = (eargs **) malloc(p * sizeof(eargs *));
```

Struct definitions for struct element cs (xcpu_context) and struct targs (execute_args):

```
typedef struct xcpu_context {
  unsigned char *memory;              
  unsigned short regs[X_MAX_REGS];    
  unsigned short pc;                  
  unsigned short state;              
  unsigned short itr;                 
  unsigned short id;                 
  unsigned short num;                 
} xcpu;

typedef struct execute_args {
    int ticks;
    int quantum;
    xcpu cs;
} eargs;
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value from `malloc()` in a C program.

Comment: Where's the code that initializes *targs?

Comment: @HansPassant - it's not there, presumably that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what the problem was. Not sure how I forgot to do that, and how I missed it when I was going over my code.

Comment: definition != declaration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have allocated an array of *pointers* in the line

```
eargs **targs = (eargs **) malloc(p * sizeof(eargs *));
```

but you haven't initialized the elements themselves.  So this segfault has nothing to do with properly using memset on the fields of a struct, but instead derives from using uininitialized memory (assuming that you don't have a loop to initialize each eargs object after you allocate the array of pointers).

Instead, if you wanted to allocate a dynamic array of `p` eargs objects (I'm using the term "objects" loosely here), you would write

```
eargs *args = malloc(p * sizeof(eargs));
if (!args) {
    /* Exit with an error message */
}
memset(&(args[i].cs), 0, sizeof(xcpu));
```

instead.  Note that `args` is a dynamically allocated array of eargs objects, *not* a dynamically allocated array of pointers, so it's of type `eargs *` rather than `eargs **`.

Comment: I think you want `&args[i].cs` if you're creating the array that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory allocation line doesn't allocate any memory for any structures, only for pointers to structures.  If you want to allocate memory for that whole array, you need to add a loop to allocate memory for the structures themselves:

```
for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
    targs[i] = malloc(sizeof(eargs));
```

Once you actually *have* structures to operate on, your `memset()` call should be fine.